# How can I use curl on windows? CMD and Powershell doesn't work

Tags: windows, powershell, curl, cmd

How can I use curl?

Every time in cmd or powershell I got the error message "Curl Command not found".. How can this be?

Comment: Make sure you a) Have it installed b) Have the location of the binary on your `PATH` variable

Comment: in powershell alias of `inovke-webrequest` is [curl](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) and that command belong to .net 4.5 powershell 4.0

Comment: 'Curl Command not found' sounds like  a curl error, not a command line error. You will need to post the actual syntax you are using, otherwise we are just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) - it has most of the commands you'll ever need.

Edit - [this](https://superuser.com/questions/344927/powershell-equivalent-of-curl) question looks helpful if it's Powershell you need specifically. `inovke-webrequest` can be used.